# How to write font color tag in csv file

Tags: html, csv

I have to call a csv file as resource file and the output needs to be displayed.Now the issue is how should I display a message like "Thanks for answering" in red colour through csv file.I need to use html tags in csv file like

```
<font color='red" ></font>
```

but the file that is calling this csv file is displaying the content along with the html tags.

Comment: Because it is text. Either Ajax and render or serve as text/HTML except that will flow the csv unless wrapped in pre

Answer (score 1):

**CSV** stands for **"Comma/Character Separated Values"** – plain text, *no* formatting, except for the optional header line and the character that separates the values.

If you need to define formatting like font colors in the source file, you would have to use another file format like **(X)HTML**, **XLS** or **RTF.**